Gradient Border and gradient Shadow with glassmorphism on card
This gives me a animated gradient effect.
The problem here is that when I make the background of the card transparent or in my case I want to apply a backdrop-filter for glassmorphism, the gradient effect is seen not only on the borders but also inside the card's background. I just want the gradient effect to be on the borders and also want the animated gradient shadow with the blur on it and also the glassmorphism on the main card.
Can anyone help me, please?


/* Card Design */

@property --angle {
    syntax: "<angle>";
    inherits: true;
    initial-value: 0deg;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.card::before,
.card::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: inherit;
    background-image: conic-gradient(
        from var(--angle), #ea2dd8, #001bf1, #ea2dd8
    );
    animation: autoRotate 2s linear infinite;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: -1;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: unset;
}

.card::after {
    filter: blur(30px);
}

@keyframes autoRotate {
    to {
        --angle: 360deg;
    }
}
<div class="card"></div>




Here is the final solution that I came up with to get the final result that I wanted.
This is the code:


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');


@property --light-font {
    syntax: "<color>";
    inherits: false;
    initial-value: #000;
}

@property --angle {
    syntax: "<angle>";
    inherits: true;
    initial-value: 0deg;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 5;
}

.card::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 16px);
    height: calc(100% - 16px);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 15px solid transparent;
    border-image: conic-gradient(
        from var(--angle), #ea2d66, #00f1cd, #ddea2d, #ea2d66
    ) 1;
    animation: autoRotate 4s linear infinite;
    filter: blur(20px);
}

.card-border {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card-border::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 8px solid transparent;
    border-image: conic-gradient(
        from var(--angle), #ea2d66, #00f1cd, #ddea2d, #ea2d66
    ) 1;
    animation: autoRotate 4s linear infinite;
}

.inner-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -0.5px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -0.5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    backdrop-filter: blur(40px);
    color: var(--light-font);
    margin: 6px;
    padding: 2rem;
}

@keyframes autoRotate {
    to {
        --angle: 360deg;
    }
}

.inner-content .card--title {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 0.8em;
}

.inner-content .card--text {
    font-size: 1em;
}
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-border">
        <div class="inner-content">
            <h3 class="card--title">Title</h3>
            <p class="card--text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas cumque enim, nisi nulla voluptatibus mollitia rerum? Enim nostrum id illo vel, necessitatibus repellendus sed animi fuga assumenda veniam commodi exercitationem?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



